# ¿Como puedo obtener la URL de un archivo subido a través de Google Form usando apps scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

```
function onFormSubmit(event) {

  record_array = []

  var form = FormApp.openById('1k2DJWsITkSpO8n4Rkjv5xdPcT28s3AdNYO_dj7G3yoc'); // Form ID
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var formCount = formResponses.length;

  var formResponse = formResponses[formCount - 1];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
  var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
    var title = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    var answer = itemResponse.getResponse();

    Logger.log(title);
    Logger.log(answer);

    record_array.push(answer);
  }


  AddRecord(record_array[0], record_array[1], record_array[2], record_array[3], record_array[4]);

}

function AddRecord(first_name, last_name, issue, comment, image) {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1onGvkBvhCDLsHCd16tlG7A19q9gncdOrGD6h68Z9KJI/edit#gid=0';   //URL OF GOOGLE SHEET;
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Hoja 1");

  dataSheet.appendRow([new Date(), first_name, last_name, issue, comment, image]);
}
```

**Solo obtengo como resultado**

[Ljava.lang.Object;@6c972f9

El codigo que se muestra funciona enlazado con una hoja de google sheet para ir almacenando los datos recolectados por el formulario de google. Puedo capturar la informacion de las otras preguntas pero la url del archivo que se sube en el formulario no se puede obtener solo logro tener un ids del objeto. ¿Como podria hacer para que esa id me de la URL?

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la forma, solo hay que usar este pedazo de código tal cual lo adjunto y en la variable urls tendrán el enlace a la imagen que se cargo.

```
var urls = answer.toString().split(",").map(function(f) { return "https://drive.google.com/open?id=" + f;}).join(", ");
```